# Text gets cut off on Match of the Day description in Smite

Tags: xbox-one, smite

The text in the description of the Match/Mode Of The Day gets cut off when the text is too long in Smite (at least on Xbox One).

[image: text gets cut off]

Even after the *First Win...* text disappears, the rest of the description is still hidden.

Is there a way to see the full description somewhere online? Or is there a way to scroll the text I just haven't discovered?

I'm using a regular HDMI set to 1080p, TV is decent size, safe zone is set to "1" (max) in Smite's video settings. I'm pretty curious because it seems an easy bug to fix (set the text to auto-scroll maybe), and also because I don't see anyone else complaining about it in forums.

Comment: What resolution is your television? And can you confirm you are using the standard HDMI connection?

I know these both have an influence on the display of text, though using a standard definition display should have more of a negative impact then a lower-resolution high definition display.

Comment: @Timelord64 yep, im using HDMI on a 1080p 47 inch tv